# .net vs other top technologies

Tags: .net

I would like to ask You all, what do You think about the future of .Net technology comparing to other top fashion technologies (for example from google).

Is it possible that within few years all solutions will be developed in other technologies than .Net. Is it worth learning .Net solutions looking into the future ?

Answer (score 3):

In a few years there will be some solutions that will be developed in .NET and some that will be developed using something else. That's how it is now and it's unlikely change much in the next few years.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible that within few years all solutions will be developed in other technologies than .Net

Unlikely. .NET even in its current form has enough momentum to survive another 10 years. And it is being developed very actively so no, it won't completely fall behind.

The more important question is what will be asked for in the future. Just technical knowledge of some specific technology won't be enough. You may want to pick up knowledge and skills from accompanying technologies and consider acquiring non-technical "soft skills". Learn about UI design, about databases, about talking to customers, about managing projects, about working teams about software as an industry. That might be more important. Technology (.NET or whatever) is just a tool. Won't do you any good if you can't see the big picture.